# Concatenate every 2 files in Power Query

Tags: excel, csv, powerquery

I have some tables (extracted from a PDF) stored as csv in a folder, following this format

```
Data-1.csv
Data-2.csv
Data-3.csv
Data-4.csv
Data-5.csv
Data-6.csv
...
```

`Data-1.csv` and `Data-2.csv` are part of the same table, i.e. each row of both files belong to the same sample.

(*Because there were too many columns, the table was split into two separate files in the PDF, which resulted in two separate csv files.*)

This sequence repeats for the subsequent files. So `Data-3.csv` and `Data-4.csv` belong together, `Data-5.csv` and `Data-6.csv` belong together, and so on...

I wish to work with this data in Excel, and before transforming the data, I need to get Power Query to horizontally concatenate every 2 files into one single table to work with.

Is there any way to do this either through the Advanced Editor or purely with the GUI?